# How to calculate coordinates of circle border using Openlayers 3

Tags: distance, openlayers-3, geometry, point

I have a point feature with given radius - let's say 1000m. I calculate the radius inside of my styling function like:

```
        var givenRadius = 1000;
        var coords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
        var projection = map.view.getProjection();
        var resolutionAtCoords = projection.getPointResolution(resolution, coords);

        var featureStyleRadius = Math.round(radius / resolutionAtCoords);

        style.getImage().setRadius(featureStyleRadius);
```

Displayed circle looks OK - I checked it by measuring its radius on the map.

Now I want to put 2 marks on it - on its center and on its border. I do it like this:

```
        var center = ol.proj.transform([lon,lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

        // center point

        map.previewLayer.getSource().addFeature(new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point(center),
                type: "dragPoint"
            })
        );

       // border point

       center[0] += givenRadius;

       map.previewLayer.getSource().addFeature(new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point(center),
                type: "dragPoint"
            })
       );
```

The center mark is positioned correctly, but the border mark is always inside the circle ( ~2/3 of its radius regardless of radius size or map zoom ) - see the picture. What is wrong with the calculation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By the look of the code you are calculating radius of Circle using `givenRadius` and `resolutionAtCoords`. But while calculating the border point you are adding hard coded `givenRadius` to `center`. So every time its adding 1000m to the center.
Instead you have to add `featureStyleRadius` to `center`.

```
 center[0] += featureStyleRadius;
```

Comment: I think, it's correct - center variable contains coordinates - according to the projection it's in meters. That's why I add the given radius of 1000m - which I expect to give me geographical coordinates of the border. Regarding the circle, OpenLayers cannot specify circle radius in meters - you have to use screen pixles. That's why I recalculate the radius for the circle each time inside of the styling function.

Comment: If the Projection used is in meters then `radius` option while creating `ol.geom.Circle` will also be taken in meters only. So you are unnecessarily calculating the radius using `resolutionAtCoords`

Comment: Sumanth - it's interesting information for me. I don't create my features "on fly", I have geojson as source, The geomerty type is "Point" (as far as I understand geojson has no circle geometry type) and I specify the radius via style for the point. As this is about 1 year old project, the radius from the style was considered to be in pixels ( it didn't change during zoom operation) and that's why I use the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is related to map distortion related to EPSG:3857 projection. I solved the issue by converting center coordinates to EPSG:4326, calculating the border point position in this projection and converting back to EPSG:3857. Doing it this way places the point exactly on the border.

Comment: Hi. I am facing the same issue. Can you post the solution please?